# How to keep a local committed change from being pushed(think IDE files)

Tags: git, version-control, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project where we use IDEA .ipr files and local property files to build and whatnot.  These files have locally relevant changes and paths in them, so I want to ensure they don't get committed back to the remote but I'd still like these files to be versioned so I can (except for this) have a fairly standard git workflow.

Is there any way to permanently mark a change or the ongoing changes to a file in a branch/repo as a 'local only' change that's never to be pushed?

At least based on my understanding adding these files to .gitignore wouldn't do what I want it to do.

Comment: You don't want them in your `.gitignore` then?

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible to move these files to a separate folder, you can use it as a submodule to keep track of local history. Otherwise, I don't know better way than cherry picking, but it's rather inconvenient.